# Get variable from object method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object, return

I'm new to objects in javascript and I'm having some problems with the following code.

```
var Color = function(color){
   this.color = color;
   this.getCode = function(){
      var colorHex;
      var colorRBG;
      switch(color){
          case "White":
              colorHex = "#ffffff";
              colorRGB = "255,255,255";
              break;
          case "Black":
              colorHex = "#000000";
              colorRGB = "0,0,0";
              break;
          default:
              return false;
      }
      return {
          colorHex: colorHex,
          colorRGB: colorRGB
      }
   }
}
```

What I want to do is get the colorHex value like this but it isn't working:

```
var newColor = new Color("White");
alert(newColor.getCode().colorHex);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it **is** working, http://jsfiddle.net/JQYED/1/ in Chrome

Comment: This is a simplified version of my actual application. Maybe I've another bug somewhere because I keep getting an "undefined" value in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this.color` instead of color in your switch statement.  Color would be undefined here and the default case would be called.

Color (the parameter) is no longer in scope, so you need to access the member variable.  Javascript does not automatically prepend this like other languages do, you have to do it manually.

Comment: I tried that but I keep getting "undefined"... I'll post the code below.

Comment: Really?? You could try: `newColor.getCode.call(newColor)` to hack it.  Changing `switch(color)` to `switch(this.color)` should work though...

Comment: I just got it! I was passing a value of "colro" instead of "color" to the function that's why. I didn't see it and this was driving me crazy. BTW, it works fine with just "color" in the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

you need to `switch(this.color)`